# issue getting last known location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, locationmanager

I test my apps on two phones (1) an LG Optima running 2.3.7 and (2) a galaxy S3 running 4.1.2.  The following code always works on the LG and always fails with a nullPointerException on the Galaxy..

```
try { //sometimes getting the last known location gets a nullpointerexception
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location myLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(myLoc.getLatitude(), myLoc.getLongitude()));
    map.animateCamera(center);
    DebugLog.debugLog("Instantiated new Location listener.  Moved camera to: " + myLoc.getLatitude() + myLoc.getLongitude() , false);

} catch (Exception e) {
    DebugLog.debugLog("Exception getting lastknownlocation - doing without" + e, false);
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code?
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with this code?

You are not checking to see if `myLoc` is `null`. [`getLastKnownLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) does not have to return a non-`null` value.

Comment: Just in case that comment shows up: Yes, he does catch the exception, but exceptions are for abnormal behavior, not expected behavior, and `null` return values are to be expected here.

Comment: That being said, while this answer does make a valid point, I think it misses the point. I think the OP was asking why `getLastKnownLocation` doesn't return anything on his Galaxy.

Comment: @IngoBürk: `getLastKnownLocation()` will return `null` when it wants to. :-) In this case, there are many possibilities: GPS is disabled, GPS has not been used (via `requestLocationUpdate()`, etc.) since last reboot, GPS has been used by not very recently and AOSP/Samsung does not cache the value that long, etc. "I think it misses the point" -- you are welcome to make whatever point you wish. *My* point is that `getLastKnownLocation()` can and will return `null`.

Comment: Ingo Burk accurately describes the point of my question (and I realize I should be checking for null instead of using Try/Catch).  Turns out Standalone Loc Services was off but Google Loc Services and Verizon Loc services was on.  I should ask isProviderEnabled.